# My iPhone 6S iCloud can't be turn off because it was never synced to a computer

Tags: iphone

I bought an iPhone 6S at Telkom four months ago, two month after my screen jammed, I took it back to the shop for repair.  I was informed that if Find my Phone" is on the repair people send it back to the shop so that we can turn it off.

They can not turn it off now because the phone was never synced to a computer.  Now no one knows what to do with my problem because the repair people will not fix it if "Find my Phone" is on.

Comment: What exactly happens if you try to turn "Find my iPhone" off in Settings?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702

Just log into iCloud.com and remove it there. If it is not your Apple ID that was linked to this you are pretty much out of luck unless you can track down the person you bought it from to help.